Does a proxy take most of its time to make the request or return the request?
Assuming I am using a proxy for multiple requests a second, does most of the time it takes come from getting the data from the desired url or from returning the data to me? I wanted to try to measure this by getting an endpoint that returned the time (in miliseconds) of when the endpoint was accessed, but I couldn't find one. Anyone knows an endpoint that could help me  test that, or could just tell me what process takes the most time for the proxy to respond?
